# Have tie extend past end of music in lilypond

Tags: lilypond, engraving, repeats, ties

I'm writing out a short snippet of music and would like to have a tie that extends past the end; How can I do this in LilyPond?

Here's what I have now:
[image: Repeat with last note "missing" a tie]

I'd like to indicate that a tie goes back to the start of the riff. (i.e. the final `e8` is tied back to the first `e` inside the volta repeat)

Using `\laissezVibrer` is close, but it ends at the barline; I'd rather have something that extends past the end.

Comment: http://www.lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/notation/modifying-shapes - The last example looks like the inverse of what you want. You may be able to play with it and get what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an invisible measure with an `e` note in it to do the tie appear.

```
\relative c, {
        \clef F \key e \major
        \partial 8 { e8 ~ }
        \repeat volta 2 {
        e8 g e4 gis8 b b4 |
        a8 cis cis b d d e, e ~ }
        \stopStaff \hide NoteHead \override NoteHead.no-ledgers = ##t e1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The shape of the *Laissez Vibrer tie* can be change with the `\shape` command.
(See: [5.4.11 Modifying shapes](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/notation/modifying-shapes.en.html))

But to get the Laissez Vibrer tie to actually extend to or beyond the repeat barline, you'll need to use a tweak on the LV, such as `\tweak X-extent`.

#### Code

```
\version "2.23.6"

\relative c, {
    \clef "bass" 
    \key e \major
    \partial 8 
        e8~ 
    \repeat volta 2 {
        e8 g e4 gis8 b b4 |
        a8 cis cis b d d e,
            \shape #'((0 . 0) (0 . 0) (2 . -0.4) (2 . -0.5)) LaissezVibrerTie
            e -\tweak X-extent #'(0 . 2.5) \laissezVibrer
    }
}
```

#### Result

[image: Laissez Vibrer tie going to the far edge of the repeat barline]